# Dwarf Fortress military and bedroom issues?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I had a working single squad military, I added another squad and a burrow to defend and I put the squads into a rotation of training one month and defending the next.  The training group just hangs around the barraks and has the not solid smiley face icon.  And the groups seem to have the wrong activity setting (it doesnt match the scedule).  Is there anything obvious that I am doing wrong?

edit: Both squads are using the same barraks, is this an issue?

When I make a bedroom I press f for free.  Only 2 of my 50 bedrooms have owners.  Am I doing something wrong?  When I make a bedroom then go back to the bed I still have the option of making a bedroom, did I make it wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Freeing" the bed, or any furniture, means making it free of the room. That is, it removes the room you just made. You just have to choose a room size with `r`. After that, a dwarf will take the room for himself (and eventually his spouse) as soon as he gets sleepy.

The reason two of your bedrooms have owners is probably that you forgot to press `f`.

I suppose you set the schedule for their "Active/Training" alert. You can check that in the military-schedule screen; the alert that you're editing is in the title and can be changed with `/*`. Make sure that they're actually in that alert: go to the `s`quads screen, mark each squad (`a` or `b`) and press `t` until the right alert is chosen.